# Ansible - use of when with include

Tags: ansible

I want to use "include" with "when" in my playbook.
Would like to know if it's possible.

Something like below

```
tasks:
 - include ps.yml
   when: "mk" in {{ host_group_names }}
```

Comment: Why don't you test this?

Comment: I have tried this and getting error, hence the question is posted here for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general constructs like

```
tasks:
- include_tasks: "tasks/{{ TODO }}.yml"
  when: ...
```

or

```
tasks:
- import_tasks: "tasks/{{ TODO }}.yml"
  when: ...
```

are possible.

You may have a look into [What's the difference between `include_tasks` and `import_tasks`?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950) and the referenced documentation for more information.

Because on depending when a variable content is created "*you would use include to deal with different workflows and take decisions based on some dynamically gathered facts*".